# The legend tells about

Tags: prepositions

The quotation from a textbook : "The legend tells about three brothers, ..." Is *tell about* correct here? Can an indirect object be omitted after tell?

Comment: Legends really tell *of* brothers.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tell?s=ts) gives 13 definitions of "**tell** with an object" and 7 of "**tell** without an object".

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've seen the examples with "tell" without an object, but there are not many with "tell+about" without an object, so I assumed it was wrong and should sound "tells us about".